# How to disable the printing of log messages output by external code?

Tags: scala, logging, external, disable

This is a general question.

In my code, I'm calling some 3rd party library. In that library, there is a logger that outputs log messages using the log factory from `org.apache.commons.logging`. These log messages are appearing in my console, alongside all the other logs from my own code. Is there an easy way to disable printing of log messages from this external library? I don't want to change general logging configurations for my program, since I want all the other logging just the way it is.

Something like the pseudocode below would be useful:

```
ignoreLogsFrom {
  // This call is the one that produces the logging
  externalLibrary.get
}
```

Basically, being able to prevent any messages that emanate from a particular block of code or even library.

Thanks if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can but it is hard to give a correct generic advice. The thins is that [`commons-logging`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) is a wrapper library: it doesn't implement the logging itself, it delegates it to some other library.

Generally steps you have to do are:

1. Find out what logger implementation is used. By default it is [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) but it might be something else (other popular choices include [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) or [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) which is another facade)
2. Find the name of the logger used by the external library. This is the parameter passed to the `LogFactory.getLog` call. Typically it would be something like the fully qualified name of the class that logs. This idea of naming is exactly the feature you want because it allows configuring loggers for different parts of the app differently.
3. Find out where the configuration for the library found #1 is stored. Typically it is some properties file or XML file (like `log4j.properties`)
4. Find out how the "level" for the given named logger is configured in that logging library. Most of the modern logging libraries support hierarchical configurations so it might easier for you to disable logging for the whole external library package rather than specific classes.

P.S. Probably disabling the whole logging for the library is not very good idea, it might be enough to raise the level to something like `WARN` or `ERROR` to significantly reduce the amount of logs but still not miss the really important st